# validate HTML form input - prevent tab if invalid

Tags: javascript, html, forms, validation

My HTML form includes a series of five related `<input type="text" />` tags, all of which need to be single-digit or two-digit numbers. I've created a JavaScript function that will test user-input against a regular expression using an if-else statement. The function works as desired when input is valid; however, I would like to have the focus remain on the input-field if input is invalid, and so far I haven't been able to make that happen.

I've tried using `document.getElementById(currseg).focus();` -- where `currseg` is dynamically set to the ID of the offending input-field. I've also tried using a `switch` statement with an individual `case` for each possible bad input-field, and with the ID of the offending field specified directly rather than calculated as a variable.

Validation testing is prompted by an `onblur` event (I've also tried using the `onchange` event) for each input-field. I have an `alert("Bad user input")` in the `else` condition, so I know the function is flowing properly to the `else` condition when input is invalid, but focus moves to the next input-field.

Everything I've tried fails to stop the progress of the focus, whether I move from the input-field by mouse-action or by tab-key.

Any suggestions how I can keep focus on a field with invalid input?

Comment: Post your code--please!

Answer (score 0):

// without any code example try to use this in the function that is checking the input - if not valid, focus that element, then return so that it stops there... ( assuming the context of the function is the input element of course... )

```
this.focus(); 
return false;
```